# How can I pull specific attributes from a Python3 module?

Tags: python, module

Im importing from the pycountries module and trying to just print out a list of all the listed countries but I can figure it out. My test code is:

```
from pycountry import countries

for num in range(0,len(countries)):
    print(countries[num])
```

Which spits out a list of all the country objects (I'll list one for example).

```
Country(alpha_2='AO', alpha_3='AGO', name='Angola', numeric='024', official_name='Republic of Angola')
```

I've tried looking at listed dir methods and tried things like:

```
print(countries[num][name])
```

What am I doing wrong? How to I pull specific things like the name or the alpha_2 from the object.

Thanks for any help and sorry for the probably stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name`, `alpha_2`, etc.  are stored as an object attribute:

You can pull it out with :

```
<country object>.alpha_2
```

or

```
<country object>.name
```

You can cycle through all the countries with a loop:

```
for country in countries:
    print(country.name)
>>>"Afghanistan"
>>>....
```

Comment: It seems that all the objects are called "Country" though (like in my example). How would I cycle through them all?